# jq: Include the lookup key as a field in the result value

Tags: json, key, jq

I have a JSON object of the following form:

```
{
  "vars": {
    "node1": {"field1": "a", "field2": "b"},
    "node2": {"field1": "x", "field2": "y"}
    "unrelated": {"blah": "blah"}
  },
  "nodes": ["node1", "node2"]
}
```

Now, I can get the fields per node (excluding `unrelated`) using the following `jq` expression:

```
.vars[.nodes[]]
```

*Output:*

```
{
  "field1": "a",
  "field2": "b"
}
{
  "field1": "x",
  "field2": "y"
}
```

My question is, how do I include the `vars` key as a field in the output, i.e.

```
{
  "node": "node1",
  "field1": "a",
  "field2": "b"
}
{
  "node": "node2",
  "field1": "x",
  "field2": "y"
}
```

The name of the key (`node` in the example) is not important.

Based on [this post](https://remysharp.com/drafts/jq-recipes) I found an approximate solution:

```
.vars | to_entries | map_values(.value + {node: .key})[]
```

which outputs

```
{
  "field1": "a",
  "field2": "b",
  "node": "node1"
}
{
  "field1": "x",
  "field2": "y",
  "node": "node2"
}
{
  "blah": "blah",
  "node": "unrelated"
}
```

But it still includes the unrelated field which is shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the `nodes` array's elements in a variable for reference. Storing the elements rather than the whole array automatically also iterates for the next step. Then, just compose your desired output objects using the `nodes` array item as object `{$node}` added to the looked-up object in `.vars[$node]`.

```sh
jq '.nodes[] as $node | {$node} + .vars[$node]'
```

```json
{
  "node": "node1",
  "field1": "a",
  "field2": "b"
}
{
  "node": "node2",
  "field1": "x",
  "field2": "y"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/b-lMFTYK5v)

Comment: Damn that was quick - thanks!